# How to reload page within range of seconds using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, reload

Simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to. I'd like to reload a webpage between every 5 and 20 second. How do I accomplish this using JavaScript? I know how to reload the page every x amount of seconds, but have no clue how to insert a range of time. I'm using Greasemonkey, if that's of any importance.

Comment: "between 5 and 20" ... ok, how do you intend on determining the delay? random number? then use Math.random() ...

Comment: post your greasemonkey script if this doesn't suffice. To produce a value from a range at random, use `Math.random() * (max-min) + min` .. like in your case: `Math.random() * (20000 - 5000) + 5000`

Comment: @robertotomás, that was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just generate a random number between 5 and 20:

```
var num = Math.round((Math.random() * 15) + 5);
```